# Can I make a Swift enum generic, so I can use its cases to infer a type for a generic class?

Tags: swift, generics, enums, type-inference, inference

Can I make an `enum` generic (different type for each case), so I can use its cases to infer a type for a generic class?

I have an example here:

```swift
class Config {
    let name: String
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class CarConfig: Config {
    static let sports = CarConfig("sports")
    static let van = CarConfig("van")
}

class BikeConfig: Config {
    static let road = BikeConfig("road")
    static let mtb = BikeConfig("mtb")
}

enum VehicleType {
    case car, bike, scooter
}

class Vehicle<C: Config> {

    let type: VehicleType
    let config: C

    init(type: VehicleType, config: C) {
        self.type = type
        self.config = config
    }

}

let bike = Vehicle(type: .bike, config: BikeConfig.mtb)

bike.config.name // mtb
```

What I would like to do is initiate a Vehicle like this:

```swift
let bike = Vehicle(type: .bike, config: .mtb)
```

I want the compiler to infer the `BikeConfig`, so I can leave it out. I want the compiler to know that a `Vehicle` with `type == VehicleType.bike` always has a `Config` that is a `BikeConfig`.

I would have to change my `Vehicle` obviously:

```swift
class Vehicle<C: Config> {

    let type: VehicleType<C>
    let config: C

    init(type: VehicleType<C>, config: C) {
        self.type = type
        self.config = config
    }

}
```

And now make `enum VehicleType` `enum VehicleType<C: Config>`.

No Idea where to go from here though. Any help? :)

[UPDATE: added `scooter` case to `VehicleType`]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it backwards, you shouldn't infer the generic type depending on the enum value, because that means you want to determine some compile-time thing (generic type) with a value that is possibly known at runtime (the value of the enum).

Therefore, we need to make the `type` parameter a compile-time-only thing, i.e. also a type parameter.

You first introduce a `VehicleTypeProtocol`, and a `struct` implementing that protocol for each of the enum case:

```
protocol VehicleTypeProtocol {
    // this associated type creates the link between a vehicle type and a config type
    associatedtype ConfigType: Config
    // this is so that we can assign to Vehicle.type
    static var type: VehicleType { get }
}

struct Car : VehicleTypeProtocol {
    typealias ConfigType = CarConfig
    static var type: VehicleType { .car }
}

struct Bike : VehicleTypeProtocol {
    typealias ConfigType = BikeConfig
    static var type: VehicleType { .bike }
}

struct Scooter: VehicleTypeProtocol {
    typealias ConfigType = BikeConfig
    static var type: VehicleType { .scooter }
}
```

And then the initialiser can be implemented like this:

```
init<T: VehicleTypeProtocol>(type: T.Type, config: C) where T.ConfigType == C {
    self.type = T.type
    self.config = config
}
```

Usage:

```
let bike = Vehicle(type: Bike.self, config: .mtb)
```

But man, this is convoluted...

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Associated Values** with the `enum` cases as whatever type you want.

Create `enum VehicleType` with `case car` with `CarConfig` and `case bike` with `BikeConfig` as the *associated types*,

```swift
    enum VehicleType {
        case car(CarConfig)
        case bike(BikeConfig)
    }
```

Now, the definition for `class Vehicle` can be modified to

```swift
    class Vehicle {
        let type: VehicleType
        init(type: VehicleType) {
            self.type = type
        }
    }
```

Create the Vehicle instance using,

```swift
    let bike = Vehicle(type: .bike(.mtb))
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that one cannot easily access the config of a `Vehicle`.